# Ошибка при загрузке pkl-файла: не найден модуль 'lib2'

Tags: python, файлы, pickle

при запуске указанного ниже кода среда выдаёт такую ошибку:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib2'

```
import  pickle
f=open('STS of probe.pkl','rb')
data = pickle.load(f)
print(data)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что необходимо сделать для решения данной проблемы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

pickle не может найти модуль lib2

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
import lib2

sys.modules['lib2'] = lib2

import  pickle

f=open('STS of probe.pkl','rb')
data = pickle.load(f)
print(data)
```

Comment: Не помогает, та же ошибка